# update panel not working behind cloudfront

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, amazon-cloudfront

I have some issue with Cloudfront Distribution. I have used a dropdownlist and a gridview in my page. When dropdownlist changed accordingly I wanted to update the gridview. Its working pretty fine on my local machine as well as on my server when I am trying with IP address.

I am using Amazon Cloudfront as CDN, Its not working behind Cloudfront.

I may suppose to add some behavior on cloudfront console to resolve this, but i am not sure about it.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: You need to be more clear that merely saying it's "not working."  What do you see in the browser's developer tools, as far as http response headers?  In your server log?  In the CloudFront logs?

Answer (score 1):

A shot in the dark here (as Michael - sqlbot says - you really need to provide more info).

Is the gridview an ASP.NET web control? If so, it might be that ASP.NET isn't recognising the CloudFront user-agent string: `Amazon CloudFront` (as opposed to something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; MSIE 9.0; WIndows NT 9.0; en-US` which is an example of a user-agent string you'd typically see if making a direct request to your site) and therefore isn't rendering the appropriate Javascript (I've seen the __doPostBack javascript omitted in these circumstances)

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx

> ASP.NET determines browser capabilities by reading the user-agent
>   information that is passed from the browser to the server during a
>   request. It compares the user-agent string that is received from the
>   browser to user agent strings that are stored in browser definition
>   files. These browser definition files contain information about the
>   capabilities of various user agents. When ASP.NET finds a match
>   between the current user-agent string and a user-agent string in a
>   browser definition file, it loads the corresponding browser
>   capabilities into the HttpBrowserCapabilities object. The properties
>   of the HttpBrowserCapabilities object can then be used to determine
>   whether the browser type that is represented by the user agent
>   supports scripting, styles, frames, and so on. **Based on these
>   capabilities, the controls on the page render Web controls using
>   appropriate markup.**

The page contains some details on how you can override this, but none of them seem ideal (i.e. explicitly targeting a specific browser / platform).

The other option is to configure CloudFront to whitelist the User-Agent header for cache behaviours that match the pages where you're using these controls (**Edit Behavior > Forward Headers > Whitelist > Add Custom: User-Agent**), but be aware this will effectively disable caching for those resources, as user-agent strings often vary per user.